# In using this tutorial script from: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails can message column be changed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, email

In using this tutorial script from: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

I am new to apps script and have been searching the forums trying to figure this out...

I'm trying to use another column in the spreadsheet to dynamically enter the salutation in the message. I thought it would be a formula like this:

="Dear "E2, + "Our 2018 Catalog is Coming Soon! Would you like a copy? "  But, then I get the error that -ADD parameter1 is text and it is looking for numbers-, (even though I found it in another help area to use the quotes to separate the cell references).

So my questions:

1.Is it possible to make dynamic changes to the message in this script? Or do I need another script in the message column to do this?

2.If I am running more than one script on the spreadsheet and connected form do I need separate script files or just separate blocks on the same file

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Adding a separate salutation to an email script

Here's the script for that tutorial:

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

I believe you wish to have a separate salutation which is at the beginning of the message portion.  It appears that you also wish to use column 5 for that data.

So if that's the case then your message would be something like this:

`var message = Utilities.formatString('Dear %s\n%s',row[4],row[1]);` [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)

This could also be accomplished this way:

`var message = 'Dear ' + row[4] + '\n' + row[1];`[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

> In either case you would put a name in column 5 and the rest of your message in column2.  If you wan't to use html in your email replace the '\n' (line feed) with `'<br />'` (line break);

The message starts with the saluation in row[4] (column 5) and the rest of the message comes from row[1] according to the tutorial which is column 2.

> The data from a getValues() command is returned in an array.  Arrays index from zero where as columns in the spreadsheet begin at 1. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

If I misinterpreted your question please ask for further assistance in comments below. I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: You interpreted perfectly! Thank you.  I understand the arrays start at 0. I did not realize I could add the columns the way you described. So I tried your suggestion and used html because another part of what I am trying to accomplish uses html. However my result wasn't quite as I had hoped. The reference to row [2] returns undefined. and the html doesn't process at all.

Comment: I tried to add a new line and it sent my comment. still learning how to use this system my apologies my code follows

Comment: var message = 'Dear ' + row[4] +',' + '</br>' + '<iframe     src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdFAG_UufiILw0O0tyd7J0ilZSOrKFXfKl2w_TPBu-w9i_MwQ/viewform?embedded=true#responses" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>' + '</br></br> Thank you,'  + '</br>' + row[1];       // Second column

Comment: and it didn't come out as code, not sure what I did wrong there :/

Comment: It's not `</br>` it's `<br />`. Is you message really an iframe tag?

Comment: the  message is the embed code for a Google Form. That's where the iframe comes in. I am trying to get the email to have the Form itself in the email (It's only 1 question) but if they answer yes it takes them to another form. I don't want to just use the link to the yes/no question because then I lose the no responses.

Comment: just fixed the line break links and got the same result

Comment: And I am trying to understand the other example you gave me and I apologize but I am completely lost as to how to even begin to use this. The get all sheets is throwing me off. I only have 1 sheet. I am VERY new at javascript. ( I normally just do html and css. I know I did the line breaks wrong I usually just use <br> I REALLY do know html and css a lot better than this example implies. I also know iframes are pretty much obsolete, but that is the code that the Google Form gave). I do appreciate the help.

Comment: I have been researching and working on this for several days and all the examples I have come across haven't quite gotten me where I wanted.

Comment: I'm sorry about that extra code.  I got my questions mixed up.  That was the answer for another question.  And in regards to the form issue, you can't put a form into an email.  The form needs a webserver to function.

Comment: So, 1. still trying to get the row [4] reference to not result in undefined and 2. still trying to get the html to work correctly. (Without the iframe I have another idea).

Comment: Well I assumed that you wanted to use column 5 for the salutation data.  Have you put that data in column 5.  If you haven't edited column five with that data then row[4] will always be undefined.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WnvL40lN8I6TRtfnbdxuWArZ1W8rb8yB3r8lqE5DgQo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Need access for that link.

Comment: how do I just let you see the spreadsheet or give you access?

Comment: Can you create a copy that we could all see?

Comment: Thanks I finally figured out that my data range was too limited! It only went to row 3.